# Yii2 : How to update the record using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am using mongodb to update the record. I am getting the team names & description from user & updating it in database following code i have written in dashboard controller

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

    $username = Yii::$app->session['username'];

    $user = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('teamdashboard');
    $record = $user->findOne(array('username'=>$username));

    $record['teams']['team_name']=$model->team_name;
    $record['teams']['team_description']=$model->team_description;
    $record['teams']['time_created']='';
    $record['teams']['team_updated']='';

    $record->save();
```

As `save()` is called it shows `Call to a member function save() on a non-object`. I want to insert new team data in existing document.

I cannot use insert because I want all the forms to be added to only one user specific document. Insert command will insert new row in the collection.

Does yii2 support embedded object mapping & operations????

Answer (score 0):

(I was wondering the same thing, for anyone wondering, looks like it isn't officially supported)

Yii 2.0 docs state:

> This extension does not provide any special way to work with
>   embedded documents (sub-documents). General recommendation is avoiding
>   it if possible.
>
> "Yii Model designed assuming single attribute is a scalar.

From:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb#working-with-embedded-documents

I was able to successfully read the items from MongoDB, just foreach the variable like a regular array.

Comment: OMG...@Entryton i knew that bcoz i tried doing this with possible other ways but couldn't find the working one. DO you hav any idea or any other way of doing this. please suggest if you have...

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to use the PECL functions of MongoDB. The PHP documentation provides plenty of examples: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php

Comment: You'll be using separate functions apart from the Yii 2.0 framework - I haven't personally tried this (I'll see when I get the time), so I don't know if it'll work out of the box inside the framework.